Blank page in Laravel/PHP + Nginx app configured in Dockerfile deployed by Cloud Run
Deployment of the laravel app all seems fine and the docker builds successfully but when I try to access the root page, all I see is a fully blank screen even though the logs seem okay?
Dockerfile:
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Set env vars
ENV NODE_VERSION=20

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    zip \
    curl \
    unzip \
    libonig-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nginx \
    git && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd zip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

# Install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

EXPOSE 8080
# Copy the application code
COPY . /var/www/html

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Add vendor binaries to PATH
ENV PATH=/var/www/html/vendor/bin:$PATH

COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

# Install project dependencies
RUN composer install

# Install Node.js and npm
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_${NODE_VERSION}.x | bash - &&  apt-get install -y nodejs

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data ./
RUN chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache && \
    chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache

RUN npm install

# Build and version Vite assets for production
RUN npm run build

# Make the file executable, or use "chmod 777" instead of "chmod +x"
RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/db-migration.sh

RUN php artisan optimize:clear
RUN php artisan route:clear
RUN php artisan route:cache
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan config:cache
RUN php artisan view:clear
RUN php artisan view:cache

# This will run the shell file at the time when container is up-and-running successfully (and NOT at the BUILD time)
ENTRYPOINT ["/var/www/html/db-migration.sh"]

db-migration.sh
#!/bin/bash
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan optimize
php-fpm -D && nginx -g "daemon off;"

nginx.conf

server {
    listen 8080;

    index index.php index.html;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    # the Cloud run service url
    server_name dev-xxxxxxxxxx.region-value.run.app;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # this should be the path of your public folder in laravel which from our dockerfile
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_buffering off;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

The Cloud Run logs:
> GET 200 9.1 KB 726 ms Chrome 131 https://dev-xxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/ 
> 169.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [17/Dec/2024:03:05:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9116 "https://console.cloud.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7))"
> 127.0.0.1 -  17/Dec/2024:03:05:39 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200

What makes me puzzled is when I deploy this on App Engine it serves the root page correctly which makes me think it's something wrong with the manual configuration of Docker and nginx since in the App Engine case I didn't have to do any of that.
Any help would be appreciated!
Edited to add:
The outcome of the curl -v command:
curl -v https://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app
* Host dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 216.xxxxxxxx, 216.xxxxxxxx, 216.xxxxxxxx, 216.xxxxxxxx
*   Trying 216.xxxxxxxx...
* Connected to dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app (216.xxxxxxxx) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256 / [blank] / UNDEF
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.a.run.app
*  start date: Nov  4 08:37:29 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 27 08:37:28 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app" matched cert's "*.us-central1.run.app"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services; CN=WR2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* [HTTP/2] [1] OPENED stream for https://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:method: GET]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:scheme: https]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:authority: dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [:path: /]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [user-agent: curl/8.7.1]
* [HTTP/2] [1] [accept: */*]
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
> 
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< x-powered-by: PHP/8.2.26
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 15:18:12 GMT
< server: Google Frontend
< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
< 
<script>console.log('Debug Objects: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:test_string' );</script><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title inertia>SST</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,500,600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const Ziggy = {"url":"http:\/\/dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app","port":null,"defaults":{},"routes":{"login":{"uri":"login","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"login.store":{"uri":"login","methods":["POST"]},"logout":{"uri":"logout","methods":["POST"]},"password.request":{"uri":"forgot-password","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"password.reset":{"uri":"reset-password\/{token}","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"parameters":["token"]},"password.email":{"uri":"forgot-password","methods":["POST"]},"password.update":{"uri":"reset-password","methods":["POST"]},"register":{"uri":"register","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"register.store":{"uri":"register","methods":["POST"]},"user-profile-information.update":{"uri":"user\/profile-information","methods":["PUT"]},"user-password.update":{"uri":"user\/password","methods":["PUT"]},"password.confirm":{"uri":"user\/confirm-password","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"password.confirmation":{"uri":"user\/confirmed-password-status","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"password.confirm.store":{"uri":"user\/confirm-password","methods":["POST"]},"two-factor.login":{"uri":"two-factor-challenge","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"two-factor.login.store":{"uri":"two-factor-challenge","methods":["POST"]},"two-factor.enable":{"uri":"user\/two-factor-authentication","methods":["POST"]},"two-factor.confirm":{"uri":"user\/confirmed-two-factor-authentication","methods":["POST"]},"two-factor.disable":{"uri":"user\/two-factor-authentication","methods":["DELETE"]},"two-factor.qr-code":{"uri":"user\/two-factor-qr-code","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"two-factor.secret-key":{"uri":"user\/two-factor-secret-key","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"two-factor.recovery-codes":{"uri":"user\/two-factor-recovery-codes","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"profile.show":{"uri":"user\/profile","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"other-browser-sessions.destroy":{"uri":"user\/other-browser-sessions","methods":["DELETE"]},"current-user-photo.destroy":{"uri":"user\/profile-photo","methods":["DELETE"]},"current-user.destroy":{"uri":"user","methods":["DELETE"]},"teams.create":{"uri":"teams\/create","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"teams.store":{"uri":"teams","methods":["POST"]},"teams.show":{"uri":"teams\/{team}","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"parameters":["team"]},"teams.update":{"uri":"teams\/{team}","methods":["PUT"],"parameters":["team"]},"teams.destroy":{"uri":"teams\/{team}","methods":["DELETE"],"parameters":["team"]},"current-team.update":{"uri":"current-team","methods":["PUT"]},"team-members.store":{"uri":"teams\/{team}\/members","methods":["POST"],"parameters":["team"]},"team-members.update":{"uri":"teams\/{team}\/members\/{user}","methods":["PUT"],"parameters":["team","user"]},"team-members.destroy":{"uri":"teams\/{team}\/members\/{user}","methods":["DELETE"],"parameters":["team","user"]},"team-invitations.accept":{"uri":"team-invitations\/{invitation}","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"parameters":["invitation"]},"team-invitations.destroy":{"uri":"team-invitations\/{invitation}","methods":["DELETE"],"parameters":["invitation"]},"sanctum.csrf-cookie":{"uri":"sanctum\/csrf-cookie","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"ignition.healthCheck":{"uri":"_ignition\/health-check","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"ignition.executeSolution":{"uri":"_ignition\/execute-solution","methods":["POST"]},"ignition.updateConfig":{"uri":"_ignition\/update-config","methods":["POST"]},"home":{"uri":"\/","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"dashboard":{"uri":"dashboard","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"profile.edit":{"uri":"profile","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"profile.update":{"uri":"profile","methods":["PATCH"]},"profile.destroy":{"uri":"profile","methods":["DELETE"]},"data-dictionary":{"uri":"data-dictionary","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"FAQ":{"uri":"faq","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"license":{"uri":"license","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"privacy-policy":{"uri":"privacy-policy","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"terms-of-service":{"uri":"terms-of-service","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"read.data-dictionary":{"uri":"read-data-dictionary","methods":["GET","HEAD"]}}};

    !function(t,r){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=r():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(r):(t||self).route=r()}(this,function(){function t(t,r){for(var e=0;e<r.length;e++){var n=r[e];n.enumerable=n.enumerable||!1,n.configurable=!0,"value"in n&&(n.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,"symbol"==typeof(o=function(t,r){if("object"!=typeof t||null===t)return t;var e=t[Symbol.toPrimitive];if(void 0!==e){var n=e.call(t,"string");if("object"!=typeof n)return n;throw new TypeError("@@toPrimitive must return a primitive value.")}return String(t)}(n.key))?o:String(o),n)}var o}function r(r,e,n){return e&&t(r.prototype,e),n&&t(r,n),Object.defineProperty(r,"prototype",{writable:!1}),r}function e(){return e=Object.assign?Object.assign.bind():function(t){for(var r=1;r<arguments.length;r++){var e=arguments[r];for(var n in e)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,n)&&(t[n]=e[n])}return t},e.apply(this,arguments)}function n(t){return n=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.getPrototypeOf.bind():function(t){return t.__proto__||Object.getPrototypeOf(t)},n(t)}function o(t,r){return o=Object.setPrototypeOf?Object.setPrototypeOf.bind():function(t,r){return t.__proto__=r,t},o(t,r)}function i(t,r,e){return i=function(){if("undefined"==typeof Reflect||!Reflect.construct)return!1;if(Reflect.construct.sham)return!1;if("function"==typeof Proxy)return!0;try{return Boolean.prototype.valueOf.call(Reflect.construct(Boolean,[],function(){})),!0}catch(t){return!1}}()?Reflect.construct.bind():function(t,r,e){var n=[null];n.push.apply(n,r);var i=new(Function.bind.apply(t,n));return e&&o(i,e.prototype),i},i.apply(null,arguments)}function u(t){var r="function"==typeof Map?new Map:void 0;return u=function(t){if(null===t||-1===Function.toString.call(t).indexOf("[native code]"))return t;if("function"!=typeof t)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function");if(void 0!==r){if(r.has(t))return r.get(t);r.set(t,e)}function e(){return i(t,arguments,n(this).constructor)}return e.prototype=Object.create(t.prototype,{constructor:{value:e,enumerable:!1,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),o(e,t)},u(t)}var f=String.prototype.replace,a=/%20/g,c="RFC3986",l={default:c,formatters:{RFC1738:function(t){return f.call(t,a,"+")},RFC3986:function(t){return String(t)}},RFC1738:"RFC1738",RFC3986:c},s=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,v=Array.isArray,p=function(){for(var t=[],r=0;r<256;++r)t.push("%"+((r<16?"0":"")+r.toString(16)).toUpperCase());return t}(),y=function(t,r){for(var e=r&&r.plainObjects?Object.create(null):{},n=0;n<t.length;++n)void 0!==t[n]&&(e[n]=t[n]);return e},d={arrayToObject:y,assign:function(t,r){return Object.keys(r).reduce(function(t,e){return t[e]=r[e],t},t)},combine:function(t,r){return[].concat(t,r)},compact:function(t){for(var r=[{obj:{o:t},prop:"o"}],e=[],n=0;n<r.length;++n)for(var o=r[n],i=o.obj[o.prop],u=Object.keys(i),f=0;f<u.length;++f){var a=u[f],c=i[a];"object"==typeof c&&null!==c&&-1===e.indexOf(c)&&(r.push({obj:i,prop:a}),e.push(c))}return function(t){for(;t.length>1;){var r=t.pop(),e=r.obj[r.prop];if(v(e)){for(var n=[],o=0;o<e.length;++o)void 0!==e[o]&&n.push(e[o]);r.obj[r.prop]=n}}}(r),t},decode:function(t,r,e){var n=t.replace(/\+/g," ");if("iso-8859-1"===e)return n.replace(/%[0-9a-f]{2}/gi,unescape);try{return decodeURIComponent(n)}catch(t){return n}},encode:function(t,r,e,n,o){if(0===t.length)return t;var i=t;if("symbol"==typeof t?i=Symbol.prototype.toString.call(t):"string"!=typeof t&&(i=String(t)),"iso-8859-1"===e)return escape(i).replace(/%u[0-9a-f]{4}/gi,function(t){return"%26%23"+parseInt(t.slice(2),16)+"%3B"});for(var u="",f=0;f<i.length;++f){var a=i.charCodeAt(f);45===a||46===a||95===a||126===a||a>=48&&a<=57||a>=65&&a<=90||a>=97&&a<=122||o===l.RFC1738&&(40===a||41===a)?u+=i.charAt(f):a<128?u+=p[a]:a<2048?u+=p[192|a>>6]+p[128|63&a]:a<55296||a>=57344?u+=p[224|a>>12]+p[128|a>>6&63]+p[128|63&a]:(a=65536+((1023&a)<<10|1023&i.charCodeAt(f+=1)),u+=p[240|a>>18]+p[128|a>>12&63]+p[128|a>>6&63]+p[128|63&a])}return u},isBuffer:function(t){return!(!t||"object"!=typeof t||!(t.constructor&&t.constructor.isBuffer&&t.constructor.isBuffer(t)))},isRegExp:function(t){return"[object RegExp]"===Object.prototype.toString.call(t)},maybeMap:function(t,r){if(v(t)){for(var e=[],n=0;n<t.length;n+=1)e.push(r(t[n]));return e}return r(t)},merge:function t(r,e,n){if(!e)return r;if("object"!=typeof e){if(v(r))r.push(e);else{if(!r||"object"!=typeof r)return[r,e];(n&&(n.plainObjects||n.allowPrototypes)||!s.call(Object.prototype,e))&&(r[e]=!0)}return r}if(!r||"object"!=typeof r)return[r].concat(e);var o=r;return v(r)&&!v(e)&&(o=y(r,n)),v(r)&&v(e)?(e.forEach(function(e,o){if(s.call(r,o)){var i=r[o];i&&"object"==typeof i&&e&&"object"==typeof e?r[o]=t(i,e,n):r.push(e)}else r[o]=e}),r):Object.keys(e).reduce(function(r,o){var i=e[o];return r[o]=s.call(r,o)?t(r[o],i,n):i,r},o)}},b=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,h={brackets:function(t){return t+"[]"},comma:"comma",indices:function(t,r){return t+"["+r+"]"},repeat:function(t){return t}},g=Array.isArray,m=String.prototype.split,j=Array.prototype.push,w=function(t,r){j.apply(t,g(r)?r:[r])},O=Date.prototype.toISOString,E=l.default,R={addQueryPrefix:!1,allowDots:!1,charset:"utf-8",charsetSentinel:!1,delimiter:"&",encode:!0,encoder:d.encode,encodeValuesOnly:!1,format:E,formatter:l.formatters[E],indices:!1,serializeDate:function(t){return O.call(t)},skipNulls:!1,strictNullHandling:!1},S=function t(r,e,n,o,i,u,f,a,c,l,s,v,p,y){var b,h=r;if("function"==typeof f?h=f(e,h):h instanceof Date?h=l(h):"comma"===n&&g(h)&&(h=d.maybeMap(h,function(t){return t instanceof Date?l(t):t})),null===h){if(o)return u&&!p?u(e,R.encoder,y,"key",s):e;h=""}if("string"==typeof(b=h)||"number"==typeof b||"boolean"==typeof b||"symbol"==typeof b||"bigint"==typeof b||d.isBuffer(h)){if(u){var j=p?e:u(e,R.encoder,y,"key",s);if("comma"===n&&p){for(var O=m.call(String(h),","),E="",S=0;S<O.length;++S)E+=(0===S?"":",")+v(u(O[S],R.encoder,y,"value",s));return[v(j)+"="+E]}return[v(j)+"="+v(u(h,R.encoder,y,"value",s))]}return[v(e)+"="+v(String(h))]}var T,k=[];if(void 0===h)return k;if("comma"===n&&g(h))T=[{value:h.length>0?h.join(",")||null:void 0}];else if(g(f))T=f;else{var x=Object.keys(h);T=a?x.sort(a):x}for(var N=0;N<T.length;++N){var C=T[N],A="object"==typeof C&&void 0!==C.value?C.value:h[C];if(!i||null!==A){var D=g(h)?"function"==typeof n?n(e,C):e:e+(c?"."+C:"["+C+"]");w(k,t(A,D,n,o,i,u,f,a,c,l,s,v,p,y))}}return k},T=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,k=Array.isArray,x={allowDots:!1,allowPrototypes:!1,arrayLimit:20,charset:"utf-8",charsetSentinel:!1,comma:!1,decoder:d.decode,delimiter:"&",depth:5,ignoreQueryPrefix:!1,interpretNumericEntities:!1,parameterLimit:1e3,parseArrays:!0,plainObjects:!1,strictNullHandling:!1},N=function(t){return t.replace(/&#(\d+);/g,function(t,r){return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(r,10))})},C=function(t,r){return t&&"string"==typeof t&&r.comma&&t.indexOf(",")>-1?t.split(","):t},A=function(t,r,e,n){if(t){var o=e.allowDots?t.replace(/\.([^.[]+)/g,"[$1]"):t,i=/(\[[^[\]]*])/g,u=e.depth>0&&/(\[[^[\]]*])/.exec(o),f=u?o.slice(0,u.index):o,a=[];if(f){if(!e.plainObjects&&T.call(Object.prototype,f)&&!e.allowPrototypes)return;a.push(f)}for(var c=0;e.depth>0&&null!==(u=i.exec(o))&&c<e.depth;){if(c+=1,!e.plainObjects&&T.call(Object.prototype,u[1].slice(1,-1))&&!e.allowPrototypes)return;a.push(u[1])}return u&&a.push("["+o.slice(u.index)+"]"),function(t,r,e,n){for(var o=n?r:C(r,e),i=t.length-1;i>=0;--i){var u,f=t[i];if("[]"===f&&e.parseArrays)u=[].concat(o);else{u=e.plainObjects?Object.create(null):{};var a="["===f.charAt(0)&&"]"===f.charAt(f.length-1)?f.slice(1,-1):f,c=parseInt(a,10);e.parseArrays||""!==a?!isNaN(c)&&f!==a&&String(c)===a&&c>=0&&e.parseArrays&&c<=e.arrayLimit?(u=[])[c]=o:"__proto__"!==a&&(u[a]=o):u={0:o}}o=u}return o}(a,r,e,n)}},D=function(t,r){var e=function(t){if(!t)return x;if(null!=t.decoder&&"function"!=typeof t.decoder)throw new TypeError("Decoder has to be a function.");if(void 0!==t.charset&&"utf-8"!==t.charset&&"iso-8859-1"!==t.charset)throw new TypeError("The charset option must be either utf-8, iso-8859-1, or undefined");return{allowDots:void 0===t.allowDots?x.allowDots:!!t.allowDots,allowPrototypes:"boolean"==typeof t.allowPrototypes?t.allowPrototypes:x.allowPrototypes,arrayLimit:"number"==typeof t.arrayLimit?t.arrayLimit:x.arrayLimit,charset:void 0===t.charset?x.charset:t.charset,charsetSentinel:"boolean"==typeof t.charsetSentinel?t.charsetSentinel:x.charsetSentinel,comma:"boolean"==typeof t.comma?t.comma:x.comma,decoder:"function"==typeof t.decoder?t.decoder:x.decoder,delimiter:"string"==typeof t.delimiter||d.isRegExp(t.delimiter)?t.delimiter:x.delimiter,depth:"number"==typeof t.depth||!1===t.depth?+t.depth:x.depth,ignoreQueryPrefix:!0===t.ignoreQueryPrefix,interpretNumericEntities:"boolean"==typeof t.interpretNumericEntities?t.interpretNumericEntities:x.interpretNumericEntities,parameterLimit:"number"==typeof t.parameterLimit?t.parameterLimit:x.parameterLimit,parseArrays:!1!==t.parseArrays,plainObjects:"boolean"==typeof t.plainObjects?t.plainObjects:x.plainObjects,strictNullHandling:"boolean"==typeof t.strictNullHandling?t.strictNullHandling:x.strictNullHandling}}(r);if(""===t||null==t)return e.plainObjects?Object.create(null):{};for(var n="string"==typeof t?function(t,r){var e,n={},o=(r.ignoreQueryPrefix?t.replace(/^\?/,""):t).split(r.delimiter,Infinity===r.parameterLimit?void 0:r.parameterLimit),i=-1,u=r.charset;if(r.charsetSentinel)for(e=0;e<o.length;++e)0===o[e].indexOf("utf8=")&&("utf8=%E2%9C%93"===o[e]?u="utf-8":"utf8=%26%2310003%3B"===o[e]&&(u="iso-8859-1"),i=e,e=o.length);for(e=0;e<o.length;++e)if(e!==i){var f,a,c=o[e],l=c.indexOf("]="),s=-1===l?c.indexOf("="):l+1;-1===s?(f=r.decoder(c,x.decoder,u,"key"),a=r.strictNullHandling?null:""):(f=r.decoder(c.slice(0,s),x.decoder,u,"key"),a=d.maybeMap(C(c.slice(s+1),r),function(t){return r.decoder(t,x.decoder,u,"value")})),a&&r.interpretNumericEntities&&"iso-8859-1"===u&&(a=N(a)),c.indexOf("[]=")>-1&&(a=k(a)?[a]:a),n[f]=T.call(n,f)?d.combine(n[f],a):a}return n}(t,e):t,o=e.plainObjects?Object.create(null):{},i=Object.keys(n),u=0;u<i.length;++u){var f=i[u],a=A(f,n[f],e,"string"==typeof t);o=d.merge(o,a,e)}return d.compact(o)},$=/*#__PURE__*/function(){function t(t,r,e){var n,o;this.name=t,this.definition=r,this.bindings=null!=(n=r.bindings)?n:{},this.wheres=null!=(o=r.wheres)?o:{},this.config=e}var e=t.prototype;return e.matchesUrl=function(t){var r=this;if(!this.definition.methods.includes("GET"))return!1;var e=this.template.replace(/(\/?){([^}?]*)(\??)}/g,function(t,e,n,o){var i,u="(?<"+n+">"+((null==(i=r.wheres[n])?void 0:i.replace(/(^\^)|(\$$)/g,""))||"[^/?]+")+")";return o?"("+e+u+")?":""+e+u}).replace(/^\w+:\/\//,""),n=t.replace(/^\w+:\/\//,"").split("?"),o=n[0],i=n[1],u=new RegExp("^"+e+"/?$").exec(decodeURI(o));if(u){for(var f in u.groups)u.groups[f]="string"==typeof u.groups[f]?decodeURIComponent(u.groups[f]):u.groups[f];return{params:u.groups,query:D(i)}}return!1},e.compile=function(t){var r=this;return this.parameterSegments.length?this.template.replace(/{([^}?]+)(\??)}/g,function(e,n,o){var i,u;if(!o&&[null,void 0].includes(t[n]))throw new Error("Ziggy error: '"+n+"' parameter is required for route '"+r.name+"'.");if(r.wheres[n]&&!new RegExp("^"+(o?"("+r.wheres[n]+")?":r.wheres[n])+"$").test(null!=(u=t[n])?u:""))throw new Error("Ziggy error: '"+n+"' parameter does not match required format '"+r.wheres[n]+"' for route '"+r.name+"'.");return encodeURI(null!=(i=t[n])?i:"").replace(/%7C/g,"|").replace(/%25/g,"%").replace(/\$/g,"%24")}).replace(this.origin+"//",this.origin+"/").replace(/\/+$/,""):this.template},r(t,[{key:"template",get:function(){var t=(this.origin+"/"+this.definition.uri).replace(/\/+$/,"");return""===t?"/":t}},{key:"origin",get:function(){return this.config.absolute?this.definition.domain?""+this.config.url.match(/^\w+:\/\//)[0]+this.definition.domain+(this.config.port?":"+this.config.port:""):this.config.url:""}},{key:"parameterSegments",get:function(){var t,r;return null!=(t=null==(r=this.template.match(/{[^}?]+\??}/g))?void 0:r.map(function(t){return{name:t.replace(/{|\??}/g,""),required:!/\?}$/.test(t)}}))?t:[]}}]),t}(),F=/*#__PURE__*/function(t){var n,i;function u(r,n,o,i){var u;if(void 0===o&&(o=!0),(u=t.call(this)||this).t=null!=i?i:"undefined"!=typeof Ziggy?Ziggy:null==globalThis?void 0:globalThis.Ziggy,u.t=e({},u.t,{absolute:o}),r){if(!u.t.routes[r])throw new Error("Ziggy error: route '"+r+"' is not in the route list.");u.i=new $(r,u.t.routes[r],u.t),u.u=u.l(n)}return u}i=t,(n=u).prototype=Object.create(i.prototype),n.prototype.constructor=n,o(n,i);var f=u.prototype;return f.toString=function(){var t=this,r=Object.keys(this.u).filter(function(r){return!t.i.parameterSegments.some(function(t){return t.name===r})}).filter(function(t){return"_query"!==t}).reduce(function(r,n){var o;return e({},r,((o={})[n]=t.u[n],o))},{});return this.i.compile(this.u)+function(t,r){var e,n=t,o=function(t){if(!t)return R;if(null!=t.encoder&&"function"!=typeof t.encoder)throw new TypeError("Encoder has to be a function.");var r=t.charset||R.charset;if(void 0!==t.charset&&"utf-8"!==t.charset&&"iso-8859-1"!==t.charset)throw new TypeError("The charset option must be either utf-8, iso-8859-1, or undefined");var e=l.default;if(void 0!==t.format){if(!b.call(l.formatters,t.format))throw new TypeError("Unknown format option provided.");e=t.format}var n=l.formatters[e],o=R.filter;return("function"==typeof t.filter||g(t.filter))&&(o=t.filter),{addQueryPrefix:"boolean"==typeof t.addQueryPrefix?t.addQueryPrefix:R.addQueryPrefix,allowDots:void 0===t.allowDots?R.allowDots:!!t.allowDots,charset:r,charsetSentinel:"boolean"==typeof t.charsetSentinel?t.charsetSentinel:R.charsetSentinel,delimiter:void 0===t.delimiter?R.delimiter:t.delimiter,encode:"boolean"==typeof t.encode?t.encode:R.encode,encoder:"function"==typeof t.encoder?t.encoder:R.encoder,encodeValuesOnly:"boolean"==typeof t.encodeValuesOnly?t.encodeValuesOnly:R.encodeValuesOnly,filter:o,format:e,formatter:n,serializeDate:"function"==typeof t.serializeDate?t.serializeDate:R.serializeDate,skipNulls:"boolean"==typeof t.skipNulls?t.skipNulls:R.skipNulls,sort:"function"==typeof t.sort?t.sort:null,strictNullHandling:"boolean"==typeof t.strictNullHandling?t.strictNullHandling:R.strictNullHandling}}(r);"function"==typeof o.filter?n=(0,o.filter)("",n):g(o.filter)&&(e=o.filter);var i=[];if("object"!=typeof n||null===n)return"";var u=h[r&&r.arrayFormat in h?r.arrayFormat:r&&"indices"in r?r.indices?"indices":"repeat":"indices"];e||(e=Object.keys(n)),o.sort&&e.sort(o.sort);for(var f=0;f<e.length;++f){var a=e[f];o.skipNulls&&null===n[a]||w(i,S(n[a],a,u,o.strictNullHandling,o.skipNulls,o.encode?o.encoder:null,o.filter,o.sort,o.allowDots,o.serializeDate,o.format,o.formatter,o.encodeValuesOnly,o.charset))}var c=i.join(o.delimiter),s=!0===o.addQueryPrefix?"?":"";return o.charsetSentinel&&(s+="iso-8859-1"===o.charset?"utf8=%26%2310003%3B&":"utf8=%E2%9C%93&"),c.length>0?s+c:""}(e({},r,this.u._query),{addQueryPrefix:!0,arrayFormat:"indices",encodeValuesOnly:!0,skipNulls:!0,encoder:function(t,r){return"boolean"==typeof t?Number(t):r(t)}})},f.v=function(t){var r=this;t?this.t.absolute&&t.startsWith("/")&&(t=this.p().host+t):t=this.h();var n={},o=Object.entries(this.t.routes).find(function(e){return n=new $(e[0],e[1],r.t).matchesUrl(t)})||[void 0,void 0];return e({name:o[0]},n,{route:o[1]})},f.h=function(){var t=this.p(),r=t.pathname,e=t.search;return(this.t.absolute?t.host+r:r.replace(this.t.url.replace(/^\w*:\/\/[^/]+/,""),"").replace(/^\/+/,"/"))+e},f.current=function(t,r){var n=this.v(),o=n.name,i=n.params,u=n.query,f=n.route;if(!t)return o;var a=new RegExp("^"+t.replace(/\./g,"\\.").replace(/\*/g,".*")+"$").test(o);if([null,void 0].includes(r)||!a)return a;var c=new $(o,f,this.t);r=this.l(r,c);var l=e({},i,u);return!(!Object.values(r).every(function(t){return!t})||Object.values(l).some(function(t){return void 0!==t}))||function t(r,e){return Object.entries(r).every(function(r){var n=r[0],o=r[1];return Array.isArray(o)&&Array.isArray(e[n])?o.every(function(t){return e[n].includes(t)}):"object"==typeof o&&"object"==typeof e[n]&&null!==o&&null!==e[n]?t(o,e[n]):e[n]==o})}(r,l)},f.p=function(){var t,r,e,n,o,i,u="undefined"!=typeof window?window.location:{},f=u.host,a=u.pathname,c=u.search;return{host:null!=(t=null==(r=this.t.location)?void 0:r.host)?t:void 0===f?"":f,pathname:null!=(e=null==(n=this.t.location)?void 0:n.pathname)?e:void 0===a?"":a,search:null!=(o=null==(i=this.t.location)?void 0:i.search)?o:void 0===c?"":c}},f.has=function(t){return Object.keys(this.t.routes).includes(t)},f.l=function(t,r){var n=this;void 0===t&&(t={}),void 0===r&&(r=this.i),null!=t||(t={}),t=["string","number"].includes(typeof t)?[t]:t;var o=r.parameterSegments.filter(function(t){return!n.t.defaults[t.name]});if(Array.isArray(t))t=t.reduce(function(t,r,n){var i,u;return e({},t,o[n]?((i={})[o[n].name]=r,i):"object"==typeof r?r:((u={})[r]="",u))},{});else if(1===o.length&&!t[o[0].name]&&(t.hasOwnProperty(Object.values(r.bindings)[0])||t.hasOwnProperty("id"))){var i;(i={})[o[0].name]=t,t=i}return e({},this.g(r),this.m(t,r))},f.g=function(t){var r=this;return t.parameterSegments.filter(function(t){return r.t.defaults[t.name]}).reduce(function(t,n,o){var i,u=n.name;return e({},t,((i={})[u]=r.t.defaults[u],i))},{})},f.m=function(t,r){var n=r.bindings,o=r.parameterSegments;return Object.entries(t).reduce(function(t,r){var i,u,f=r[0],a=r[1];if(!a||"object"!=typeof a||Array.isArray(a)||!o.some(function(t){return t.name===f}))return e({},t,((u={})[f]=a,u));if(!a.hasOwnProperty(n[f])){if(!a.hasOwnProperty("id"))throw new Error("Ziggy error: object passed as '"+f+"' parameter is missing route model binding key '"+n[f]+"'.");n[f]="id"}return e({},t,((i={})[f]=a[n[f]],i))},{})},f.valueOf=function(){return this.toString()},f.check=function(t){return this.has(t)},r(u,[{key:"params",get:function(){var t=this.v();return e({},t.params,t.query)}}]),u}(/*#__PURE__*/u(String));return function(t,r,e,n){var o=new F(t,r,e,n);return t?o.toString():o}});

</script>        <link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/build/assets/app.3ae73135.css" /><link rel="modulepreload" href="http://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/build/assets/app.caeba767.js" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/build/assets/app.3ae73135.css" /><script type="module" src="http://dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app/build/assets/app.caeba767.js"></script>      </head>
  <body class="font-sans antialiased">
    <div id="app" data-page="{&quot;component&quot;:&quot;Welcome&quot;,&quot;props&quot;:{&quot;jetstream&quot;:{&quot;canCreateTeams&quot;:false,&quot;canManageTwoFactorAuthentication&quot;:true,&quot;canUpdatePassword&quot;:true,&quot;canUpdateProfileInformation&quot;:true,&quot;hasEmailVerification&quot;:false,&quot;flash&quot;:[],&quot;hasAccountDeletionFeatures&quot;:true,&quot;hasApiFeatures&quot;:false,&quot;hasTeamFeatures&quot;:true,&quot;hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature&quot;:false,&quot;managesProfilePhotos&quot;:false},&quot;auth&quot;:{&quot;user&quot;:null},&quot;errorBags&quot;:[],&quot;errors&quot;:{},&quot;canLogin&quot;:true,&quot;canRegister&quot;:true,&quot;laravelVersion&quot;:&quot;10.48.25&quot;,&quot;phpVersion&quot;:&quot;8.2.26&quot;},&quot;url&quot;:&quot;\/&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;8ceb1b66ea558abedda254600c023f2d&quot;}"></div>  </body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host dev-xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-central1.run.app left intact


I am not sure what is wrong but you are doing a db migration and site optimize on every HTTP request. That is the wrong way to design a Laravel application for Cloud Run. Use the curl command with the verbose option. Post the output in your question. A response of 9116 bytes is being returned, the key is what is being returned. The content might indicate the problem.

I think that app engine does all the heavy lifting for you. By this i mean, that probably it build image for you and binds 8080 port to outside 8080 port. Btw, i do not see any docker compose file ? Did you create it and bind ports and i also do not see how you run the container itself. We do only see the configuration for services and  Dockerfile with layers. I would advise to combine multiple RUN layers(clean up) into one RUN layer like php artisan optimize:clear && php artisan route:clear and so on... .

And btw, if you did this COPY . /var/www/html you do not need to do that COPY composer.json composer.lock ./ you already copied everthing intially. And why do you need this extension docker-php-ext-install ?

Thanks, I've updated it with the curl dump
Right, for cloud run you can't use docker compose it seems, just one Dockerfile so Cloud Run itself does the container running itself
Ok thanks! will compress the layers as possible and will remove the extra COPY command

And why do you need this extension docker-php-ext-install

This was from a guide I followed I guess it's not needed

Your Cloud Run app is returning an HTML page. You are not receiving a blank page. Load the site in Chrome, select "Inspect" and review what the debugger shows you. Using curl and Chrome Inspect (or similar) should have been debugging steps that you performed before posting a problem.
